# multiply sqrt(-1) to matrix in c++ and Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am absolutely new in c++ and wrote the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

mat tens(mat A,mat B,mat C){
    mat E = kron(kron(A,B),C);
    return E;
}

mat ii(2,2,fill::eye);// make a 2*2 identify matrix

mat ee = ii.col(0); // extract a column vector
mat gg = ii.col(1);

mat a1=tens(ee,gg,gg);
mat a2=tens(gg,ee,gg);
mat a3=tens(gg,gg,ee);
mat s23=a3*a2.t();
mat H=a1*a1.t()+a2*a2.t()+a2*a1.t()+a1*a2.t();

mat rhot(float t,mat y){ 
    return sqrt(-1)*(-H*y+y*H)+0.5*(2*s23*y*s23.t()-s23.t()*s23*y-  y*s23.t()*s23);
}

int rk4(mat y,float dt,float tmax){
    float t = 0.;
    mat ydot1, ydot2, ydot3, ydot4;
    while (t < tmax)
    {
        ydot1 = rhot(t, y);
        ydot2 = rhot(t+0.5*dt, y+0.5*dt*ydot1);
        ydot3 = rhot(t+0.5*dt, y+0.5*dt*ydot2);
        ydot4 = rhot(t+dt, y+dt*ydot3);
        cout<< t<< " "<< a3.t()*y*a3 <<endl;
        y=y+ (dt/6.0)*(ydot1 + 2.0*ydot2 + 2.0*ydot3 + ydot4);
        t=t+ dt;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()//int argc, char** argv)
{
    rk4(tens(ee,gg,gg)*tens(ee,gg,gg).t(),0.01,4.);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in sqrt(-1) in the bellow function:

```
 mat rhot(float t,mat y){ 
    return sqrt(-1)*(-H*y+y*H).....
```

On the other hand, I want to know how it is possible to multiply sqrt(-1) to a matrix in Armadillo.

Comment: To add to Wintermute's answer.  The `tens()` function above is inefficient, as it's copying the input matrices.  In C++ all arguments to functions are by default passed by value, which essentially means copying.  To prevent that, change the declaration `tens(mat A,mat B,mat C)` to be `tens(const mat& A, const mat& B, const mat& C)`.  The `&` is critical.  You can then use the `tens()` function as before, ie. `tens(ee,gg,gg)`

Comment: Thank you very much. As I am new in c++, I don't know many issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqrt(-1)` is not representable as `double` (which models real numbers). The result of `sqrt(-1)` is NaN (not a number), not the complex number i you expect.

To make Armadillo work with complex numbers, use `cx_mat` instead of `mat` everywhere, and instead of `sqrt(-1)`, use `std::complex<double>(0, 1)` or, if you can rely on C++14, `using namespace std::literals;` and `1i`.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid,small and of course, helpful coment!